# valign vs text-align in HTML

Tags: html, css, markup, semantic-markup

I can't figure out the difference between valign vs text-align in HTML in context with the following code:

```
    <table width="500" border="0">
  <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
   <h1>Main Title of Web Page</h1>
   </td>
      </tr>

  <tr valign="top">
      <td style="background-color:#FFD700;width:100px;text-align:top;">
      <b>Menu</b><br />
    HTML<br />
      CSS<br />
  JavaScript
     </td>
   <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;text-align:top;">
      Content goes here</td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFA500;text-align:center;">
     Copyright © 2012</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proper values for text-align are left|right|center|justify as it is horizontal, while the valign is vertical so it's top|middle|bottom|baseline. You can also use inherit on both.

Plus, text-align is css while valign is an html attribute. I think align is the html equivalent to text-align, while vertical-align is equivalent to valign.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp

If you switch text-align to "bottom", you'll notice it doesn't move as bottom isn't valid for text-align. The default (i think) is top. If you put "vertical-align:bottom" though, it will go to the bottom.

A simple web search will find you these answers...

Answer (score 19):

`valign` (html attribute) is equivalent of `vertical-align` in css

`align` (html attribute) is equivalent of `text-align` in css

**html attribute versions are deprecated in favour of css**

`vertical-align` positions block elements (e.g. `div`) vertically inside other block elements

`text-align` positions inline elements (e.g. `span`, default text) inside block elements horizontally

Comment: `vertical-align positions block elements` - this is wrong statement. It positions inline elements vertically.

Answer (score 3):

The `text-align` is for horizontal aligning in CSS and styles, where `vertical-align` is for vertical alignment. Then we have `align="center"` `valign="top"` are the correspondant attributes in the HTML for the same purpose.

Read more about **HTML** and **CSS**, this is my suggestion.

Comment: hmm so SO is for experts only? i think its more that this Q has probably been asked a zillion times that gets peoples goat

Comment: No, but this generic question for HTML and CSS, which you could find almost anywhere on the web. Try searching **align**, **valign**, **text-align**, **vertical-align** in Google. You will see the exact definitions on the very first page, for sure.
The idea here, is to share a share problems and respective solutions, as far as I get it, not an encyclopedia.

Answer (score 0):

valign will vertically align all elements, whereas text-align is specifically for text.

Answer (score 0):

A value of `top` for `text-align` is not supported (*only `left | center | right | justify | start | end`*).. so it does not do what you expect it ...

The [`text-align` <sup>MDN docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align) property is for horizontal align.

The vertical align you witness in your example is because of the `valign="top"` property of the `tr` element.

Look at your example without the `valign` at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/PvtAU/ and you will notice this.

`valign` is only valid for [`tr` <sup>MDN docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/tr) and [`td` <sup>MDN docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/td) elements, and is deprecated in html 4.01 and obsolete in html5.
Use [`vertical-align` <sup>MDN docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align) instead..

Answer (score 0):

The value of `text-align: top;` is not valid css, `text-align` is horizontal not vertical. This is where `valign="top"` comes into play. Putting in `valign="left"` is not valid the same as `text-align: top;` is not valid. `valign` is vertical.