# Change verticalAlign in div from javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am trying change vertical-align style of div like using below code but it doesn't do that, how can I change vertical-align position

```js
title = document.getElementById("text");
title.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
```

```css
body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: I made your code into a code snippet, so far it shows no text. Could you add the necessary code to create a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Do you want to align the Text-Content use text-align in div ? Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8757326/2932057)

Answer (score 0):

You have two subtle problems in your approach.

1. you need to set the `height` of #text in order to be able to vertically align its contents
2. `vertical-align` is not the style property you require. Nowadays, the vertical align is better obtained with a combination of `display:flex` and `align-items: center`

see this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/83bf4qdh/

Answer (score 0):

First: your div has no content so you won't see anything.

Second: vertical-align works only for inline or flex blocks. `div` is block by default so it won't work. You can set

```css
display: flex;
```

or

```css
display: inline;
```

for it to work then.